# Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

Tags: xcode, for-loop, swift, xcode6-beta6

```
func loadThumbnails() {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory:NSString = paths[0] as NSString
    var error:NSError?
    let fileManager = NSFileManager()
    let directoryContent:AnyObject = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, error: &error)!

    thumbnails = [QSPhotoInfo]()

    for item:AnyObject in directoryContent {
        let fileName = item as NSString
        if fileName.hasPrefix(kThumbnailImagePrefix) {
            let image = loadImageFromDocumentsDirectory(fileName)
            var photoInfo = QSPhotoInfo()
            photoInfo.thumbnail = image;
            photoInfo.thumbnailFileName = fileName
            thumbnails += photoInfo
        }
    }
}
```

the compile error is below:

> Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

what does this menas?

who can help me ,thks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Apple states in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html):

> The for-in loop performs a set of statements for each item in a range,
>   sequence, collection, or progression.

Right now, `directoryContent` is just conforming to protocol `AnyObject`, so you can't use for loops over it. If you want to do so, you have to do something similar to the following:

```
for item in directoryContent as [AnyObject] {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: thks a lot ,upgrade from beta3 to beta6,appear many new compile error.it seems many github project need to rebuild for xcode-beta6,any good advise for me ?

Answer (score 5):

`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` returns an `NSArray`, whereas you are casting it to `AnyObject`. The solution is to cast it to either `[AnyObject]?` or `NSArray`:

```
let directoryContent: [AnyObject]? = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, error: &error)
```

or

```
let directoryContent: NSArray? = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, error: &error)
```

Then use an optional binding before the for loop:

```
if let directoryContent = directoryContent {
    for item:AnyObject in directoryContent {
```

Looking at the `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` documentation, it states it always returns an array - so what said above can be reduced to unwrapping the return value to either a swift or objc array, with no need to use the optional binding:

```
let directoryContent: [AnyObject] = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, error: &error)!
```

or

```
let directoryContent: NSArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory, error: &error)!
```