# Iterate over a JavaUtilList in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sqlite

I have a list translated with J2Objc:

```
var userDtoIds:JavaUtilList = // some list
```

Now I want to iterate over this list with a `for in` loop. I tried:

```
for iten in userDtoIds {
}
```

Error: Type 'JavaUtilList' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

With:

```
 let arr:IOSObjectArray = userDtoIds.toArray()
 for iten in arr {      
 }
```

I got the Error: Type 'IOSObjectArray' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

The only way how it works is:

```
for var i:Int32=0; i < userDtoIds.size(); i++ {
}
```

**Can I use a `for in` loop to iterate over a JavaUtilList?**

Edit:

The following code leads to a runtime error:

```
var list = userDtoIds as! NSArray
for item:String in list as! [String] {
}
```

Comment: you need to cast userDtoIds to AnyObject or NSArray , follow this [type-anyobject-does-not-conform-to-protocol-sequencetype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563655/type-anyobject-does-not-conform-to-protocol-sequencetype)

Comment: @pawan Could you please post an answer. I do not know how to do it. The link does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension IOSObjectArray: Sequence {
   func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
       // Create iterator
   }
```

[Here is a wonderful article on conforming custom collection types, even if you are using j2objc](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139591/building-custom-collection-swift).