# Type 'AnyObject' does not conform protocol 'sequenceType'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, anyobject

So this is my code, I get an error in the following line, saying "Type 'AnyObject' does not conform protocol 'sequenceType'":

```
for bar in allBars {
```

I tried the solution proposed here ([Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563655/type-anyobject-does-not-conform-to-protocol-sequencetype)) but it causes Xcode to bug

I'm very new on IOS so this might be some stupid stuff

```
func loadBars(){
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("donnes", ofType: "json")
    let filename: String = "donnees.json"

    do{
        let data = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped)
        do{
            let bars: AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
            if let bars = bars as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                print(bars)

                let allBars = bars["bars"]

                for bar in allBars {

                    let nouveauBar = Bar(id: bar["id"], name: bar["name"], adress: bar["adress"], url: bar["url"], image_url: bar["image_url"], tags: bar["tags"], longitude: bar["longitude"], latitude: bar["latitude"])

                    bars += nouveauBar
                }

            } else {
                print("Level file '\(filename)' is not valid JSON")
            }
        }catch {
            print("Level file '\(filename)' is not valid JSON: \(error)")
        }


    }catch {
        print("Could not load level file: \(filename), error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

And here is the beginning of the .json file:

```
{
"code": 200,
"bars": [{
    "id": 1627,
    "address": "100 Rue Saint-Martin, 75004 Paris, France, Opera and Les Halles, Paris",
    "name": "Caf\u00e9 Beaubourg",
    "url": "/bar/paris/opera-and-les-halles/cafe-beaubourg",
    "image_url": "https://prh-wbb-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/generic_640_480/WBB%20holding%20image3_54abcf7d218d1_55b8d2128eabb.jpg",
    "tags": "Bar, Gay, Cafe, Dinner, Lunch",
    "latitude": 48.860033826521,
    "longitude": 2.3508920416641
}, {
    "id": 1259,
    "address": "19 Rue Beaubourg, 75004 Paris, France, Bastille and the Marais, Paris",
    "name": "Georges",
    "url": "/bar/paris/bastille-and-the-marais/georges",
    "image_url": "https://prh-wbb-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/generic_640_480/WBB%20holding%20image4_54abcf6d1f68d_55b8d2015bb13.jpg",
    "tags": "Serves Food, Great View, Rooftop, Terrace, Rock",
    "latitude": 48.8603,
    "longitude": 2.35097
}]
```

}

Comment: use SWIFTYJSON to parse json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if let bars = bars as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
```

you could write

```
if let bars = bars as? [String: AnyObject],
    let allBars = bars["bars"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
```

This already gives you the `allBars` array. Then the compiler knows that each `bar` in `allBars` will have type `[String: AnyObject]` (short for `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`) which allows you to use `bar` as a dictionary. You still have to unwrap the properties such as `id` and `name`, you can do that similarly to my code above.